# Linear Algebra: Isomorphism Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, group-isomorphism, vector-space-isomorphism

Here are the initials:

---

$\nu$ is a vector space

$\beta=\begin{Bmatrix}b_{1},\cdots,b_{n}\end{Bmatrix}$ is a basis for $\nu$

---

Argument:

coordinate mapping $\Phi_{\beta }:\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by sending a vector $v$ $\epsilon$ $\nu$ to its coordinate vector $\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}_{\beta}\epsilon\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is an isomorphism between $\nu$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

---

Questions:

1)  Explain why each vector $v$ $\epsilon$ $\nu$  gets sent to exactly one coordinate vector $\begin{bmatrix}v\end{bmatrix}_{\beta}\epsilon\mathbb{R}^{n}$

2) Show how $\Phi_{\beta }:\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ respects vector addition and scalar multiplication.

3) Explain why the linear transformation $\Phi_{\beta }:\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is one-to-one.

4) Explain why the linear transformation $\Phi_{\beta }:\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is onto.

---

I'm not to sure how to prove all this. I can show it if I had numbers but with arbitrary terms I'm not sure how to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: If $[v]_\beta = x$ and $[v]_\beta = y$, show that $[0]_\beta = x-y$.  By the definition of a basis, show that this means that $x - y = 0$, so that $x = y$.  Thus, $v$ can only get sent to one coordinate vector.

2: Prove that the mapping $\Phi_\beta$ is linear as you would normally prove that a map is linear.

3: Similar to 1. If $v_1$ and $v_2$ get sent to the same coordinate vector, then $v_1 - v_2$ gets sent to the $0$-vector.  Use the definition of a basis to show that $v_1 - v_2$ has to be zero, which in turn implies that $v_1 = v_2$.

4: Starting with $x \in \Bbb R^n$, find a $v \in \nu$ such that $\Phi_\beta(v) = x$.

Comment: So for part 1 would I show that since the only solution to 0 is the trivial solution? Each scalar has to be 0?

Comment: That's right ${}$

Comment: But how does that explain that it can only be sent to one coordinate vector?

Comment: Ah, I made a mistake.  I'll have it fixed in 2 minutes

Comment: Fixed.  It's a similar argument, you see...

Comment: Alright, I got 1, 2, and 3. However, I'm not understanding what you wrote for 4?

Comment: If $x=(x_1,\dots, x_n)$, let $v=x_1b_1+\cdots+x_n b_n$

Comment: How would that prove onto?

Comment: What's your definition of onto?

Comment: In this question, Range is all $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Right. If $x$ is a vector in $\Bbb R^n$, how do you show that $x$ is in the range?

Comment: If there is an output?

Comment: What? The range is the set of outputs. What you need to check is whether there is a corresponding input.

Comment: Ok, I'm not understanding how to show this though

Comment: We have to show that for every output $x$, there is a $v$ such that $\Phi_\beta(v) = x$.  $v = x_1b_1 + \cdots + x_n b_n$ is that $v$.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!